# Как упростить вёрстку?

Tags: css3, html, html5, css, вёрстка

[image: css]
Не прошу писать мне готовый код, просто намекнуть, как сделать лучше.
На изображении 2 блока. Нужно, чтобы каждый из них занимал 50% ширины. А контент внутри этих блоков прижимался внутри к краю с отступом, чтобы при разных разрешениях всю ширину занимал только фон. В принципе кажется, что ничего сложно нет, но я запутался :)
Сделал один общий id="webhost" и в нем два класса с еще двумя классами :) В одном классе фон с 50% шириной (wleft и wright), а в другом - контент (wleft-row и wright-row). Получаются куча флоатов и куча кода. Можно же ведь как-то попроще сделать?

```
   <div id="webhost">
           <div class="wleft">
        <div class="wleft-row"> 
        <h2></h2>
        <p></p>
           <a href="#"></a>
           </div>
  </div>
    <div class="wright">
        <div class="wright-row">    
        <h2></h2>
        <p></p>
            <a href="#"></a>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Намекаю. Представьте, что у вас две одинаковые коробки, вы поставили их рядом друг с другом. Теперь вы можете складывать в обе коробки кучу всего и знаете, что это и есть граница. Теперь представьте, что вы эти коробки взяли и положили в другие коробки с большей площадью. Т.е площадь увеличилась, а коробки так и сохранили свой прежний размер.

Немного подсказки:
Вы говорите, что два блока с 50% шириной. Хорошо, теперь в эти два блока вложите еще по блоку, но с внутренними отступами и задайте им ширину и высоту. Теперь вы можете вкладывать, что угодно. У вас будет соблюден отступ и ширина.

Если моя подсказка слишком запутана, то могу привести пример с кодом)

Comment: В принципе так и сделал, просто думал, что есть вариант попроще. Например с background:linear-gradient с шириной для каждого цвета 50%. Но потом сделал так как описывали Вы :)